# Button on the right of text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an Android UI. I want to place a button on the left of text with a border, but don't have a clue how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve partial overlay you can place the `TextView` and the `Button` inside a `RelativeLayout` and have some right/end margin applied to the `TextView`.

If your `Button` always have the same text you can trial-find an appropriate value for the right margin you need to apply to the `TextView`.

If the `Button` text is variable you can overwrite the margin in code once the layout has been computed. Here is an attempt to what you might need (it has some made up values for some of the dp sizes, but I think you can get the idea):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#ff20ff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something very simple, make Liner or Relative Layout, make a drawable resource a shape of any color, and then you put your textview there and the button.

Comment: ah i forgot you call the drawable resource as drawable backdround in the linear or relative layout

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
view.setButtonDrawable(new StateListDrawable());

view.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.img, 0,
                    0, 0);
```

Comment: call you tell me how can i bring the button to the left side on the border.